# secure a directory that hosts links

Tags: php, apache2

to login to the site, a loginForm is submitted (POST) to login.php script.

Mysql is queried and if the username/md5 pw match, then a few $_SESSION variables are set.

The user is redirected to a secured page using header('Location: securedLinks.php').

On securedLinks.php I check for the $_SESSION variables using if (ISSET($_SESSION)){}.

This is working, if the user is authenticated, then they can click on the links to access files. The links are on securedLinks.php, like so: `http://mysite/files/link1.pdf`

If you copy the link from securedLinks.php then open a new browser, you can navigate directly to the link, w/out having to go through securedLinks.php.

What is a method to secure the mysite/files directory? Is this done on the web server tier, apache2 using directives?

Thanks

**Edit - Solution**

apache2 virtualServer config:

```
<Directory "/something/path/securedDirectory">
Options -Indexes
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

securedLinks.php returns a listing of files

```
$fileList = scandir($securedDirectory);
```

jQuery loops over $fileList, adding links to securedLinks.php

```
$.each(linkObj, function(k,v){
    var a = "<a href='reportLoader.php?fileName=" + v + "'>" + v + "</a><br>";
    $("#reportLinks").append(a);
});
```

jQuery also stops the default click and strips out href, then sets the download

```
$(document).on("click", "#reportLinks a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = $(this).attr("href");
    getPdf(params);
});

function getPdf(urlParams){
    if (urlParams.length > 0){
        window.location.href = urlParams;
    }
}
```

finally, here's how reportLoader.php streams the file

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['myVar'])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST['fileName'];
    $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/securedDirectory/".$fileName;
    if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
        $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
        $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
        $ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
        switch ($ext) {
            case "pdf":
                header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "doc":
                header("Content-type: application/msword");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
            case "docx":
                header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            break;
        }
        header("Content-length: $fsize");
        header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); //this is incompatible with IE8
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        readfile("$fullPath");
        fclose ($fd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if you want to make a directory private you could use apache to restrict the directory with an .htaccess file or set the permissions on the directory to only apache.  This way no outside access can be obtained, and then when you need the files, apache can server them up for you on a specific page that is secure to the user. So on the script securedLinks.php apache would have access to these files, and the directory, therefore would be able to serve them up for the user to view.